# AM/PM in my timepicker is being converted to a different language

Tags: java, jsf, timepicker

my AM/PM in my time picker is converted in to japanese.

web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

my page.

```
<h:inputText class="input-small" value="#{item.startDate}">
   <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm a"/>
</h:inputText>
```

on my local, my system timezone is hongkong the value on my time is something like: `10:43 AM` which is fine. But when i uploaded my project on my web server ( japan ) it is displayed as `10:43 午後` i need the value to be AM/PM and not in japanese.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be caused by different default locales on both systems. You could test this by setting the `locale` attribute on `f:convertDateTime` to the correct value which enforces the given locale.